# How formally to prove commutativity of disjunctions with natural deduction?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

How do I formally prove that $p \lor q$ can be written as $q \lor p$ using natural deduction? I realize this may very well be trivial but still can't properly prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From proofs.openlogicproject.org

[image]

Comment: Damn, I knew it would be trivial... thinking too complicated gets me nowhere it seems. Thank you!

Comment: @Gidelix Natural deduction does get annoying fiddly at points, so hold on to that feeling for later! ^_^

Comment: yeah, after writing a rather simple deduction in 42 lines due to not being able to use deMorgan without proving it first (assignment criteria) my logical thinking was kind of mushy. Thanks for the link to openlogicproject as well, didn't know that was a thing :D

Answer (score 1):

You can derive $\psi\vee\phi$ from $\phi$ and also from $\psi$. Therefore, you can derive $\psi\vee\phi$ from $\phi\vee\psi$.

[image: or commutativity]